# Rails create model that contain two foreign keys from different tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model

I have 2 models: `User` and `Game`. And I need to create model that contain fk from those models (`game_id` and `user_id`). It means that `User` can have several games. 
I generated this model:

```
class CreateUserGames < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :user_games do |t|
      t.references :game, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

So, main question that I need to add button 'Take' (or smth like that) and if user signed in, it creates record in this table with id of current game and id of current user. 
What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the link_to with a post method and create an action to handle that. For example:

```
link_to "Take", 'your_action_url', method: post, game_id: 'your_game_id'
```

also, remember to create the action url on `route.rb`:

```
  match "your_action_url" => "your_controller#take_game", via: [:post]
```

then, you create your action with something like:

```
def take_game
   user_id = current_user.id #(if you're using devise)
   if UserGame.create!(game_id: params[:game_id], user_id: user_id)
     #handle success and return to the view
   else
     #handle error
   end
end
```

Guess it's a good way to do that. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey! Thanks alot, dude! Its absolutely that I needed! Unfortunately I dont have enough reputation to thank you